# How to update bound listbox in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I thought this would have been very simple - but I cannot see the updated data in a Listbox.  I have read a number of posts but can't quite get my head around it.

The data type I am binding to:

```
public class ScanDataItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string mainData { get; set; }
    public string responseData { get; set; }

    public ScanDataItem(int id, string mainData, string responseData)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.mainData = mainData;
        this.responseData = responseData;
    }

}
```

In the form class:

```
public BindingList<ScanDataItem> scanData;
```

in the form_load

```
scanData = new BindingList<ScanDataItem>();
scanData.AllowNew = true;
scanData.Add(new ScanDataItem(1, "message", "test"));
mainList.DataSource = scanData;
mainList.DisplayMember = "mainData";
mainList.ValueMember = "id";
```

So - the initial data displays in the event where I want to add an item, but when I add an item to the BindingList - then nothing happens.

```
scanData.Add(new ScanDataItem(1, "some message" , "test"));
```

Comment: Is the new item added in the UI Thread, or are you Task-running / Thread-starting  `scanData.Add()`? Or similar detail you forgot to mention?

Comment: Hmmm… In my small tests, your code appears to work as expected. I put the code … `scanData.Add(new ScanDataItem(1, "some message" , "test"));` … into a simple button click event and the `ListBox` updated as expected. Unless you are trying to do this under another thread as Jimi notes… then …where is your code executing the line of code…. `scanData.Add(new ScanDataItem(1, "some message" , "test"));` … ? …

Comment: Yes - I guess it must be.  I am adding to the scanData object from within an event that is a serial port read ( scales ) .. so is that on another thread or something?

Comment: Yes, it is. As you can see in the Docs: *The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object*. If you're using the `SerialPort` component (hence, your code most probably is inside a Form class), just change `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => scanData.Add(new ScanDataItem(1, "some message", "test"))));` -- Otherwise, pass an [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) delegate to the procedure that handles the Serial Port's `DataReceived` event -- Data binding doesn't work cross-Thread.

Comment: THank you! problem solved ( and I understand what is going on better now ) .  Cheers.